# how to get directly bitmap image from inkcanvas (in wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, ocr, inkcanvas

I am doing an OCR project. I must to get an image from input in inkcanvas to process in the next step, i.e. translate this image to an two-dimension array.

I am confused about that how to get a bitmap image from inkcanvas to process. I have been searching for a solution from many sources but a lot of them just save the inkcanvas to file-stream.

please help me!
thanks so much

Comment: Here is your answer. Save as Image in all format from InkCanvas.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51207941/7300644

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is older but I also had to get a bitmap from the ink canvas. So to answer the question on how to get a bitmap directly from the ink canvas, here is a solution. hope it still helps.

```
    private System.Drawing.Image ConvertInkCanvasToImage()
    {

      //create temporary InkCanvas or send it in as a parameter
      InkCanvas inkCanvas = new InkCanvas();      
      inkCanvas = viewModel.InkCanvas;

      //render bitmap
      RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)inkCanvas.ActualWidth, (int)inkCanvas.ActualHeight, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
      rtb.Render(inkCanvas);
      BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
      encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
      rtb.Render(inkCanvas);

      //save to memory stream or file 
      System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
      encoder.Save(ms);  

      //creat bitmap with memory stream or file
      Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);
      return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: If you need to copy the image to the clipboard, then after you save it to memory stream,  you have to create a bitmap from the memory stream and copy it to the clipboard, like this:




`var img = Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(img);`

Answer (score 1):

Check this blog post:
http://www.centrolutions.com/Blog/post/2008/12/09/Convert-WPF-InkCanvas-to-Bitmap.aspx

That gets you a byte array for the bitmap, since you're doing OCR that should be enough.